# No grub windows and ubuntu legacy mode

Tags: boot, grub2

I installed windows first in legacy mode (on 500gb of my HDD), then installed Ubuntu in legacy mode as following:
1) 1 GB ext4 /boot mount
2) 2 gb swap
3) the rest ext4 / mount
In the boot install dropdown menu i picked the partition from 1)

It installed succesfully, I restarted and it booted straight into windows 10.
I rebooted, tried holding SHIFT to get in the grub, no luck.
I rebooted, went in the boot menu, but there was nothing in the EFI section (some people could put linux or whatever first there so it would boot in that OS) no succes.
I tried enabling the grub through this workaround:
https://itsfoss.com/no-grub-windows-linux/
Again with no succes.
I tried booting my live ubuntu usb, and click on try now (to try and adapt grub settings in the terminal there) but i keep getting a "LZMA data corrupt" error.

Anyone could help me out on what I could try next?

Comment: May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info If you have UEFI hardware and are dual booting with newer Windows better to be in UEFI mode. Grub only boots working Windows and Windows will keep turning fast start up back on. Then you have to temporarily reinstall a Windows boot loader to get into Windows to turn fast start up back off.

Comment: @oldfred can I install ubuntu in uefi mode even though my windows is installed in legacy mode?

Comment: @oldfred also i'm not able to run from a live installer, i get the "LZMA data corrupt" error. I tried different USB sticks, i use RUFUS to burn the iso on my usb (latest stable ubuntu version), none are working.

Comment: If Windows is legacy/BIOS/CSM boot mode, you need to install Ubuntu in legacy/BIOS boot mode. Often better if hardware is UEFI to have Windows in UEFI mode. Many have to try different install software, or different flash drives. Some even different USB ports. Check that download is correct with md5sum: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM Other tools to create flash drive: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb